# Syntax error in Insert into vb.net and access 2007

Tags: vb.net, connection-string, sqlcommand

**Really need help about this...**
**Syntax error on Insert Into Statement**

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

```
    Try
        connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =|DataDirectory|\StJudeData2.accdb;persist security info = false"
        conn.ConnectionString = connstring


        Dim SqlQuery As String = "INSERT INTO StJudeData2(FirstName,MiddleInitial,LastName,Block#,Lot#,Telephone,HomeSticker#,Phase#) VALUES (@FirstName,@LastName,@Block#,@Lot#,@Telephone,@HomeSticker#,@Phase#)"
        Dim SqlCommand As New OleDbCommand(SqlQuery, conn)


        With SqlCommand
            .CommandText = SqlQuery
            .Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", TextBox1.Text)
            SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", TextBox2.Text)
            SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleIntial", TextBox3.Text)
            SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Block#", TextBox4.Text)
            SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lot#", TextBox5.Text)
            SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telephone", TextBox6.Text)
            SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomeSticker#", TextBox7.Text)
            SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phase#", TextBox8.Text)

            SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End With

        MsgBox("Records had been save!")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        conn.Close()


    End Try
```

Comment: Oh Yeh. Got new error Syntax error in query date expression

Answer (score 1):

When you use characters like # in your column names, you should remember to put these names in square brackets because they are confusing Access

```
 Dim SqlQuery As String = "INSERT INTO StJudeData2 " & _
  "(FirstName,MiddleInitial,LastName,[Block#],[Lot#],Telephone,[HomeSticker#],[Phase#]) " & _
  "VALUES (@FirstName,@LastName,@Block,@Lot,@Telephone,@HomeSticker,@Phase)"
```

As a side note, do you really need them?. You will have this problem every time you write query for this table, so, if it is not too late, change these column names.

As noted below, there is another error in your query, the MiddleInitial field has no parameter set for it, you need to add another parameter for MiddleInitial field after the @FirstName (The position is important for OleDb that doesn't recognize the parameters by their names)

Comment: Yeh I really need them.

Comment: Then you have no choice but use square brackets around them. However the parameters could be written without them

Comment: in the query, there is a field `MiddleInitial` and no value for it

Comment: Oh Yeh. Got it. Got new error too Syntax error in query date expression. >.<

Comment: @TunZarniKyaw nice catch, then another error will be raised